# How can i get it so i dont have my character infinitely jump?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the code i have wrtten so far which makes the player controlled charcter be able to jump contanstantly i only want them to be able to jump when on the ground.

```
void Update()
    {
        this.transform.Translate(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, 0);
        xdirectionMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * runspeed; //GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") 

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))  //makes player jump
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpdistance, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

Comment: add a check to see if they are on the ground then.

Comment: C# is not UnityScript. UnityScript is not C#.

Comment: not been set to unityscript it was visual studio which is what i am using to code

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you only allow jumping when the character is grounded. One approach to check for that is to use a downwards raycast and see if the hit is below a certain threshold:

```
void Update()
{
    print(IsGrounded());
}

bool IsGrounded()
{
    const float distanceToGround = 1f;
    return Physics.Raycast(
        transform.position, -Vector3.up, distanceToGround) != null;
}
```

Another is to use a CharacterController component and check its bool:

```
CharacterController controller = null;

void Start()
{
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void Update()
{
    print(controller.isGrounded);
}
```

Another is to listen for a collision event and set a bool:

```
bool collides = false;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    print(collides);

    collides = false;
}

void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
{
    collides = true;
}
```

Note that sometimes, it's good usability practice to allow a bit of leeway so the user can jump even if they miss the ground by a few pixels, or miss the timing by a few milliseconds. Good luck!

Comment: the bit of leeway you're talking about is generally called coyote time if the OP wants to search about that.

Comment: And also, since the code shown is using a rigidbody, maybe it's best to do a CapsuleCast or SphereCast just to make sure there is a collision if the ground is uneven or for some reason there's a hole in the floor.

Answer (score 0):

Add a bool to check if player is grounded, add Vectors and Colliders to determine where player is, relative to the ground.

```
private BoxCollider2D box;
Vector3 maxValue= box.bounds.max;
Vector3 minValue=box.bounds.minValue;
Vector2 x = new Vector2(max.x, minValue.y -0.1f);
Vector2 y = new Vector2(minValue.x, minValue.y - 0.1f);
Collider2D ground = Physics.OverlapArea(x,y);
bool jump = false;
if (ground != null)
{
    jump = true;
}
```

Finally you can add the bool to your Input, for example,

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && jump == true)
{
    //player jump 
}
```

Comment: does this work if the ground below changes in the y value or would it have to have the ground a the same level to allow the player to jump?

Comment: @JamesRogers The `BoxCollider2D` is attached to the ground, so no matter what y level the ground is at, it will work.

Comment: @JamesRogers actually the box collider is used to check for other colliders(the ground) to determine if player is in air or on ground